# C# reading a file into a 2-D array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, arraylist

my project is using txt file as db, each line in the txt file will be something like "abc,cdf,ghi,zkl"

now i am reading line by line from the text file and split the line into an array data[] by ","
but i want to put this array into another main array called datas[], so i can store this datas[] array in memory for the whole class to use,

i dont want to fix datas[]  array size as the txt file records will be growing.

what can i do in this case? i tried to make datas[] as arraylist then stored data[] array in it , but error showed.

```
class user
{
    ArrayList userDatas = new ArrayList();

    public user()
    {
        readUsers();
    }

    public void readUsers()
    {
        string line;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("user.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
            string[] rc = line.Split('|');
            for (int i = 0; i < rc.Length; i++)
            {
                temp.Add(rc[i]);

            }
            userDatas.Add(temp);
        }

    }

    public bool login(string ic, string password)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < userDatas.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList temp = userDatas;
            if ((temp[1] == ic) && (temp[2] == password))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use ArrayList()! It's there now for backwards compatibility with old code.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're storing passwords in the clear.  That is WRONG. You hash the password (preferrably using bcrypt) and when the user logs in, you hash their attempted password and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 2):

Of course if you don't mind being a little cute you should be able to do it with one line coutesy of LINQ:

```
string[][] LinesSplitByComma = File.ReadAllLines("file path").Select(s => s.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ArrayList`, use `List<string>` for temp and `List<string[]>` for `userDatas`.

When you're done filling them, you can convert to an array by simply calling `userDatas.ToArray()`

Also, your error might be here:

```
ArrayList temp = userDatas;
if ((temp[1] == ic) && (temp[2] == password))
{
      return true;
}
```

You're not first checking to make sure temp has 3 or more elements before referencing indexes 1 and 2.  Also, why are you creating temp only to assign it to userDatas?  Why not just say:

```
if (userDatas.Count() >= 3 && (userDatas[1] == ic) && (userDatas[2] == password))
   return true;
```

**EDIT**

As requested, here's my original code, though you already have much of it written, but here it is (you're code didn't show up at first):

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader();
        List<string[]> datas = new List<string[]>();
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        string line;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            datas.Add(line.Split(','));
        }

        string[] datas_array = datas.ToArray();
```

Comment: I can now - let me have a look

Comment: Yours would still work, it's just using the generic version of `ArrayList` would be a bit simpler and more elegant.  Again, what's the error you're getting

Comment: thanks, please dont remove your code, i am studying, thanks for your help again